# Why does networkx have so many random graph generators?

Tags: python, networkx

Networkx appears to have a lot of random graph generators. Why are there so many and which should I choose?

fast_gnp_random_graph,

gnp_random_graph

dense_gnm_random_graph

gnm_random_graph

erdos_renyi_graph

binomial_graph

https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generators.html

Comment: Because there are many ways to generate them. Which one oyu should use completely depends on your application.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta If they all generate equivalent networks, why would I not always choose the fastest one among them then?

Comment: I don't think @GiacomoAlzetta was saying they generate equivalent networks.  But there are lots of ways to generate "random" networks, because the properties you want your random network to have may vary.  For those algorithms that do generate equivalent networks - sure choose the fastest - but which one is fastest may depend on the specific parameters of the network.

Comment: You can have dense or sparse Erdos-Renyi networks.  Which algorithm is fastest to generate them will be different.  Of course there are other kinds of random networks.  Depending on your application, you may be happy with an Erdos-Renyi network.  However, maybe you need a specific degree distribution - then you need configuration model.

Answer (score 3):

Some of them really are identical – i.e. just aliases for the purpose of convenience.
E.g. `gnp_random_graph` = `binomial_graph` = `erdos_renyi_graph`.

They all generate the same type of graph but some use different algorithms that perform better or worse depending on the parameters/properties of your graph (size, density, ...). So there is no single best choice. (Even if there were, it may be of academic interest to some people to also have alternate algorithms available – e.g. for speed comparisons.)

Some also differ in the way you define/paramerterize your graph. E.g. Some use the number of nodes and the probability to grow an edge, while others are defined by the number of nodes and the number of edges.

Depending on your application one may be preferable to the other.

Comment: `fast_gnp_random_graph` is also equivalent to those 3, but runs much faster if the probability of connecting any pair is very low.